# How to concatenate a row variable taken from a different query to an existing query?

Tags: php, mysql

I was hoping to get anyone's opinion on why this certain variable won't print out. Variable $sum from the $qsl_ query is not printing along with the other table row data.

```
<?php

        $sql_ = "SELECT SUM(`points`) AS value_sum FROM `history` WHERE `userid` = '$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_);
        #echo mysql_error();
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $sum = $row['value_sum']; 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

        $myData = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<table id=\"table\" class=\"table table-striped\">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Plate Number</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        </tr></thead>";

        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['firstName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['lastName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['model'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['Year'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['plateNumber'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['city'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['country'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

        ?>
```

This is my current output where the points column won't produce:

[image]

I apologize if my code appears inefficient, I am a struggling student fanatic of PHP. I appreciate direct answers; however, learning is my key here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` tell you?

Comment: That's weird. It appears as "array (size=1) 'value_sum' => null ". This query worked fine on another page.

Comment: where are you getting $id from?

Comment: Oh yes, I will update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $sql = "SELECT users.*, sum(history.points) as points FROM users left join history on users.id=history.userid group by users.id";

    $myData = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<table id=\"table\" class=\"table table-striped\">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Plate Number</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    </tr></thead>";

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['firstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['lastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['model'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['Year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['plateNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['country'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['points'] . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Omg, you are a king! Could you tell me how to order them by the points in total?

Comment: ` $sql = "SELECT users.*, sum(history.points) as points FROM users left join history on users.id=history.userid group by users.id ORDER BY points ASC";` I think or DESC if you need hier values come first

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you so much for the help! May I just ask for future reference, If i wanted to add a constraint like WHERE `city` = '$postedCity'. Where does that go?

Comment: I found the answer here, for anyone looking for it: $sql = "SELECT users.* , sum(history.points) as points FROM users left join history on users.id=history.userid WHERE users.city = '$_POST[city_search]' group by users.id ORDER BY points DESC";

Mr. Kim you are a king!

Comment: :-) thank you for your words :-) by  the way - it is insecure practice to put $_POST directly to the query string. you should better use mysqli or pdo model to connect to database and bind parameters. read some here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that. I am still learning the basics and at the same time I iterate towards solidifying my coding practices so that they will be safe. Thank so much for the source, I am enjoying the read very much !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I might have had my code jungled, thank you @abhi and @msfoster for your healthy inputs.

```
<?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $myData = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<table id=\"table\" class=\"table table-striped\">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Plate Number</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        </tr></thead>";

        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

        $id = $record['id'];

        $sql_ = "SELECT SUM(`points`) AS value_sum FROM `history` WHERE `userid` = '$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_);
        #echo mysql_error();
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $sum = $row['value_sum'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['firstName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['lastName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['model'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['Year'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['plateNumber'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['city'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['country'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        }

        echo "</table>";

        ?>
```

My output is finally:

[image]

Comment: I answered my question in case anyone might find this code useful (somehow) :D

Answer (score -1):

query is correct but as you shown 
var_dump($row) = "array (size=1) 'value_sum' => null " 
so it have 'null' because of that its showing blank;

but for this you can use **join** also .

Answer (score -1):

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` returns an array of "rows". Since you want the first row you need to access it `$sum = $row[0]['value_sum'];`